# Inspecting Grails services in plugins through GrailsClassUtils

Tags: grails-2.0

I am developing a Grails (v. 2.2.1) application that loads several Grails plugins. I would like to inspect such plugins at startup through some code in my Bootstrap.groovy.

For each plugin I would like to inspect the services and detect implemented interfaces so that I know, for each service, what features are available. 
I’ve started with the following code that inspects only those plugins whose name match a particular pattern.:

```
def pluginManager = PluginManagerHolder.getPluginManager();
pluginManager.getAllPlugins().each {
    if(it.name.startsWith("cn") && it.name.endsWith("Connector")) {
       …
       String serviceName = ….
       …

       Object service = ctx.getBean(serviceName);
       println “Service:” + service /

       Class[] ints1 = GrailsClassUtils.getAllInterfaces(service);
       Class[] ints2 = GrailsClassUtils.getAllInterfacesForClass(service.getClass());
       …    
    }
}
```

The println returns the service object, which seems existing in the form I was expecting. 
Then I’ve tried the two lines/alternatives of code after and both fail.

The first one returns:

No signature of method: static org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsClassUtils.getAllInterfaces() is applicable for argument types: (…) …

The second one returns:

No signature of method: static org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsClassUtils.getAllInterfacesForClass() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) …

The second alternative is a little puzzling as the signature of the method is 
getAllInterfacesForClass(java.lang.Class clazz)

Two questions:

1. Is this a viable method to find out what the services implements?
2. What am I missing in relation to GrailsClassUtils?